# convert php code to c# trying make program convert myisam db to innodb

Tags: c#, php, mysql

i'm trying to make a app to convert MYISAM to INNODB

if found this php script code

```
<?php
    // connect your database here first 
    // 

    // Actual code starts here 

    $sql = "SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
        WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'your_database_name' 
        AND ENGINE = 'MyISAM'";

    $rs = mysql_query($sql);

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs))
    {
        $tbl = $row[0];
        $sql = "ALTER TABLE `$tbl` ENGINE=INNODB";
        mysql_query($sql);
    }
?>
```

then i try to make it iin c#

```
public static void UpdateDB()
        {
            using (var cnn = new MYSQLCONNECTION(con))
            {
                cnn.Open();
                using (var cmd = new MYSQLCOMMAND("SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = '" + db + "' AND ENGINE = 'MyISAM'", cnn))
                {
                    using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {

                        }   
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

and i can't understand what is this codes mean

```
$tbl = $row[0];
$sql = "ALTER TABLE `$tbl` ENGINE=INNODB";
mysql_query($sql);
```

i tried and i failed can any one help me with this

thanks

Comment: Do you mean you don't know what the SQL statement means, or how to convert it?

Comment: When all else fails [R.T.M](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/alter-table.html) That statement changes a table to be an INNODB table. The main thrust of what you are doing. The `$tbl` will be replaced with a table name. Dont know how to do that in C#, its been a while. But you probably should know how to do that.

Comment: _yes this I mean_ ?? What do you mean

Comment: ahhh , lemme check thanks for your reply

Comment: the first comment is for daan the second comment is for riggsfolly